# Improve appearance of ListPointPlot3D with respect to Plot3D

Tags: plotting, filling

I solve a PDE of which solution is physically a probability density $p$. Due to the algorithm the result is a $n\times m$-matrix which will be plotted by `ListPointPlot3D` and colored by a blend like this

```
f[x_, y_] := Exp[-x^2 - 100 y^2]

ListPointPlot3D[
  Transpose[Table[f[x, y], {x, -3, 3, 0.05}, {y, -3, 3, 0.05}]], 
  ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Green, Yellow, Red}, #3] &), 
  Filling -> Axis, PlotStyle -> PointSize[0], PlotRange -> Full, 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "p"}, DataRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}}
]
```

[image: ListPointPlot3D]

Let's say that there would be an analytical result, so no discretization is required, then this result could be represented with `Plot3D`:

```
Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
  ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Green, Yellow, Red}, #3] &), 
  PlotRange -> Full, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "p"}, Mesh -> None, 
  PlotPoints -> 100
]
```

[image]

The appearance of `Plot3D` is much better. How can i improve the appearance of the `ListPointPlot3D` so that there are no gaps between the discretized points?

EDIT: `ListPlot3D` is not an option. Let $m0$ be the data of the solution. E.G.

```
ListPlot3D[m0, ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Green, Yellow, Red}, #3] &), 
  Filling -> Axis, PlotRange -> Full, Mesh -> None
]
```

[image]

But an `ListLinePlot3D` has a much better visual outcome in this case.

```
ListPointPlot3D[m0, 
  ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Green, Yellow, Red}, #3] &), 
  Filling -> Axis, PlotStyle -> PointSize[0], PlotRange -> Full
]
```

[image]

But it is still not perfect. Depending on the `ViewPoint` (or `ViewAngle`) one can see gaps or a unsmooth transition.

Comment: Try `ListPlot3D`.

Comment: And `PlotPoints-> 100` or the equivalent of increasing the number of $x$ and $y$ points in the iterators.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @Pickett with minor, cosmetic tweaks:

```
 f[x_, y_] := Exp[-x^2. - 100. y^2.] + .0000001;

 ListPlot3D[
 Transpose[
     Table[f[x, y], {x, -3, 3, 0.05}, {y, -3, 3, 0.05}]], 
 ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Green, Yellow, Red}, #3] &),
 Filling -> Axis,
 PlotStyle -> PointSize[0],
 PlotRange -> Full,
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "p"},
 DataRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}},
 Mesh -> None]
```

And you mentioned that your function is a probability density.  As such, normalize your function first.  Alternatively, notice that your function is a `MultinormalDistribution`:

```
 Plot3D[
  PDF[MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {{1, 0}, {0, .001}}], 
  {x, y}], 
  {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},
 PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: In my case, this is not the better solution. I've oversimplified the problem. The matrix is actually a list of $(x,y,p)$-vectors which are on the $(x,y)$-plane dense. You can see an edit to my question.

Comment: @Drakonomikon The `ListPlot3D[m0, ...]` solution looks great in version 10.1.  But if the $(x, y, p)$ values obey your explicit `Exp[ ]` equation, then they *do* obey a `MultinormalDistribution`, so why not use such a distribution and avoid all your problems?

Comment: Due to a licensing issue we have not received an update. This will take a few weeks. So i'm still using 10.0.1. Does that really make a difference?

Comment: The problem is not the `Exp[]` function. The result of the PDE looks like an exponential-function but it isn't. Using `MultinormalDistribution` does not change the problem and it is even not possible.

Comment: @Drakonomikon Did you post a Multinormal distribution (`Exp[-ax^2 - by^2]`) and then claim that the function you seek to plot *isn't* such a distribution?

Comment: No, the first two plot-examples are multinormal distributions. But for convenience only. The actually data is similar to a multinormal distribution. But that is not the point. The problem is, that due to the algorithm only $(x,y,p)$-vectors are available. The distribution shape of the result does not matter. The `ListPointPlot3D` looks okay, because the points are close to each other. But the closer the points the stronger is the Moiré pattern.